# Resetting Drop down field values to default in Angular js 1.5.6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to reset all drop down values to empty values,currently I am default the state and metro based on zip code I am getting from back-end.

Here one more issue is angular removing the empty select option once I select any value in the drop down, so reset button should reset field values to empty values.

I wrote code for reset but it is not working. Any help on this appreciated.

Javascript Code:

```
$scope.myFunction = function()
{
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form name="myForm">
            <div ng-show='showFilterData' class="box2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Filters</h3>
                        </div>
                     <span  ng-show="!myForm.$valid && myForm.$error.required">Please select the mandatory field</span> 
                    <div class="dropdown-fields">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, productItem) in productItems" >
                                <label>{{productItem.Name}}</label> 
                                <span class="error-message"  ng-show="!productItem.APTS_UI_Selection_Optional__c">*</span>                               
                                <p>                                  
                                    <div ng-if="!productItem.APTS_Dependent_Attribute__c && selectedProductItem.Id != '01t30000003iyXzAAI'"> 
                                          <select name="statesel" ng-init="Select" class="form-control" style="width:auto" ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name], key, productItem)" ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.ddData | orderBy:'Name'" ng-required="true">
                                         </select>

                                        </div>

                                    <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Dependent_Attribute__c && selectedProductItem.Id != '01t30000003iyXzAAI'">
                                        <select name="metrosel" ng-init="Select" class="form-control" style="width:auto" ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name], key, productItem)" ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.filterData | orderBy:'Name'" ng-required="true" >
                                          </select>

                                         </div>

                                </p>                                 
                                <p> 
                                     <div ng-if="!productItem.APTS_Dependent_Attribute__c && selectedProductItem.Id == '01t30000003iyXzAAI'"> 
                                          <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Display_Order__c == '1' "> 
                                            <select  ng-init="Select" class="form-control" style="width:auto" ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name], key, productItem)" ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.ddData | orderBy:'Name'" >
                                             </select>
                                            </div>

                                          <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Display_Order__c == '3' "> 
                                            <select  ng-init="Select" class="form-control" style="width:auto" ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name], key, productItem)" ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.ddData" >
                                              </select>
                                              <h1>pandu</h1>
                                            </div>   

                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Dependent_Attribute__c && selectedProductItem.Id == '01t30000003iyXzAAI'"> 
                                        <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Display_Order__c != '4'">                                           
                                        <select  ng-init="Select" class="form-control" style="width:auto" ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name], key, productItem)" ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.filterData | orderBy:'Name'" >
                                        </select>
                                      </div>

                                         </div>
                                         <div ng-if="productItem.APTS_Display_Order__c == '4' && selectedProductItem.Id == '01t30000003iyXzAAI'">
                                             <div>
                                                 <input type="text" ng-blur="attoerneyPRValue(attoerneyPR)" ng-model="attoerneyPR"/>

                                             </div>

                                    </div>
                               </p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="getresults-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"  ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid "  ng-click="getattributeCombination()">Search</button>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()"> reset </button>
                            <div><br></br></div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="showSuccessAlert" >
                                <span> <strong> Your results are more than 600 lines. First 600 lines have been shown. Please narrow results using the provided filters.</strong></span>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool('showSuccessAlert')">x</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Does the below code worked for you ?

Comment: Hi @TaylorRahul thanks you for taking time looking into my issue, unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with below tweak in your myFunction , since all the select box has this array as a model with different keys, you can reset the array in your function if it contain any other model name you need to reset this as well, like i reset `attoerneyPR` model manually in function

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    $scope.productItem = {};
    $scope.attoerneyPR = '';
}
```

Comment: Hi @taylor rahul thanks you for taking time looking into my issue, unfortunately it is not working.